# Disable WebView's Vertical Scrolling in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native Expo app, with dependencies

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "~0.55.2",
"react-navigation": "^2.12.1"
```

Currently I am making a screen that contain three components

An image on the very top, a webview in the middle and a list on the bottom

I Want those three components to wrapped inside a ScrollView so I can navigate between them easily (Let's see the WebView's height overflow the screen)

The problem is:
The webview have its own scroll (Vertical scroll), so when I tried to do a scrolling gesture, the image just stayed on top, and ONLY the content of the webview scroll

How to make the webview disable its scrolling behavior, and extent its height to fit its content?

Answer (score 2):

`WebView` has a props called `scrollEnabled`, by default it's set to `true` so you can set it to `false` like so `scrollEnabled={false}`

**But:** this works only in iOS

check the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/webview#scrollenabled

Comment: how about android?